# ggmap with ggsubplot creates blank map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to place some plots on a map but nothing appears on the map. Here is a reproducible example. The first plot shows how each subplot should look. The second excludes the map but the subplot sizes are too large. The last is one attempt at the final product. I have tried many permutations but this has me stuck. Thanks in advance.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(ggsubplot)

pDat <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(13L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 32L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L), .Label = c("PW-29", "PW-31", "PW-32", "PW-33", "PW-35", "PW-36", "PW-37", "PW-38", "PW-39", "PW-40", "PW29", "SD-03", "SD-03a", "SD-12", "SD-18", "SD-19", "SD-27",   "SD-29", "SD-30", "SD-31", "SD-32", "SD-33", "SD-35", "SD-36", "SD-37", "SD-38", "SD-40", "SD-41", "SD-42", "SD-43", "SD-44", "SD30"), class = "factor"), Lat = c(47.292351, 47.292351, 47.289376,   47.289376, 47.288299, 47.288299, 47.288014, 47.288014, 47.287338, 47.287338, 47.29476, 47.293246, 47.293246, 47.293246, 47.293246, 47.293259, 47.293259, 47.293259, 47.292206, 47.292206, 47.292206,   47.291523, 47.291523, 47.291523, 47.290496, 47.290496, 47.289826, 47.288262, 47.288262, 47.287735, 47.286672, 47.290059, 47.290059, 47.290482, 47.28852, 47.28852, 47.288377), Long = c(-73.098418,    -73.098418, -73.101282, -73.101282, -73.102558, -73.102558, -73.102178, -73.102178, -73.103016, -73.103016, -73.096432, -73.096412, -73.096412, -73.096412, -73.096412, -73.098245, -73.098245, -73.098245, -73.097552, -73.097552, -73.097552, -73.100022, -73.100022, -73.100022, -73.099395,    -73.099395, -73.100051, -73.101199, -73.101199, -73.101895, -73.102629, -73.100954, -73.100954, -73.100184, -73.102246, -73.102246, -73.101477), SBD_ft = c(0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 10, 0, 6, 2, 5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 2.5, 0.5, 0, 3, 0.5, 0, 2.5, 0.5, 0, 2.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 3, 0, 6, 0), SED_ft = c(20, 4, 2, 9, 2, 12, 2, 8, 4, 7, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5, 0.5, 4.5, 2.5, 0.5, 5, 2.5, 0.5, 4.5, 2.5, 0.5, 3.5, 2.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 2), Cluster = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Location",    "Lat", "Long", "SBD_ft", "SED_ft", "Cluster"), row.names = 5:41, class = "data.frame")

BBox<-c(-73.01, 47.28, -73.1, 47.30)
#Base <-get_map(BBox,zoom=13,source='google',maptype = 'hybrid')
Base_z <-get_map(BBox,zoom=15,source='google',maptype = 'hybrid')

fm0<-ggmap(Base_z,legend = "none",
  base_layer=ggplot(aes(x=Long,y=Lat),data=pDat))

# Example subplots
ggplot(pDat,aes(ymin=SBD_ft,ymax=SED_ft,xmin=0,xmax=1,fill=Cluster))+
  facet_wrap(~Location)+
  geom_rect() +
  scale_y_reverse()

# TEST 1, need to control size of subplots
ggplot(pDat)+
  geom_subplot(aes(x=Long,y=Lat,group=Location,
    subplot=geom_rect(data=pDat,aes(ymin=SBD_ft,ymax=SED_ft,xmin=0,xmax=1,fill=Cluster))))

# Final , does not work
fm0+
  geom_subplot(aes(x=Long,y=Lat,group=Location,
    subplot=geom_rect(data=pDat,aes(ymin=SBD_ft,ymax=SED_ft,xmin=0,xmax=1,fill=Cluster))))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the plot under TEST 1 line, I get `At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`.

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10) with ggsubplot in R 3.1.0, what R version are you using?