# Plotting bar chart on map using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have to plot bargraphs on a map using `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
q=ggplot(data=mapindia, aes(long, lat, group=group,colour)) + geom_polygon(fill="#FF9999", colour="black") +coord_map()
q=q+geom_point(aes(x=LATITUDE, y=LONGITUDE,group=state_name),data=religion)+coord_map()
q <- q+geom_subplot2d(aes(long,lat,subplot = geom_bar(aes(value,fill=fact))), ref = NULL, width = rel(0.8), data = simdat)
print(q)
```

But got the following error:

```
## Using binwidth 2.12
## Using binwidth 2.13
## Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found
```

My data sets

```
dput(head(mapindia, 100))
structure(list(long = c(72.94823, 72.948775, 72.96202, 72.964302, 
72.968211, 72.970708, 72.964092, 72.956172, 72.943367, 72.931651, 
72.93708, 72.948365, 72.947281, 72.938496, 72.930794, 72.924501, 
72.918209, 72.910397, 72.893036, 72.879257, 72.878837, 72.880537, 
72.882884, 72.882518, 72.885103, 72.88869, 72.892337, 72.89675, 
72.904402, 72.911528, 72.924481, 72.944418, 72.950934, 72.955821, 
72.962662, 72.95561, 72.94823, 73.043316, 73.042348, 73.040185, 
73.035095, 73.028379, 73.024913, 73.022964, 73.022209, 73.025029, 
73.032294, 73.03815, 73.043791, 73.046396, 73.047159, 73.053124, 
73.066142, 73.080464, 73.092181, 73.105632, 73.114977, 73.134375, 
73.147935, 73.15217, 73.156084, 73.16586, 73.178224, 73.182115, 
73.182861, 73.181982, 73.182834, 73.190533, 73.20268, 73.213414, 
73.227186, 73.235096, 73.237463, 73.230614, 73.219987, 73.211622, 
73.210741, 73.202164, 73.190022, 73.177, 73.165391, 73.150641, 
73.1438, 73.13869, 73.133474, 73.13281, 73.136697, 73.160516, 
73.178507, 73.192372, 73.206024, 73.208846, 73.214068, 73.225464, 
73.236084, 73.258275, 73.268327, 73.272309, 73.269801, 73.265777
), lat = c(20.466602, 20.459483, 20.44602, 20.43615, 20.424953, 
20.412235, 20.398937, 20.402725, 20.410493, 20.404022, 20.392923, 
20.385058, 20.379266, 20.374414, 20.375353, 20.377813, 20.380272, 
20.382634, 20.390107, 20.390654, 20.405481, 20.415684, 20.428257, 
20.443762, 20.453246, 20.460464, 20.466909, 20.47418, 20.482435, 
20.486774, 20.501579, 20.496404, 20.491097, 20.487117, 20.477538, 
20.469934, 20.466602, 20.219381, 20.232198, 20.240647, 20.24748, 
20.255641, 20.261145, 20.266745, 20.276713, 20.279753, 20.284505, 
20.287736, 20.293816, 20.299704, 20.309768, 20.311575, 20.320982, 
20.333331, 20.339792, 20.343499, 20.343211, 20.346733, 20.349013, 
20.353571, 20.362402, 20.374462, 20.372372, 20.361166, 20.351196, 
20.342554, 20.331159, 20.330208, 20.330965, 20.330202, 20.329626, 
20.325824, 20.314522, 20.304079, 20.303419, 20.292882, 20.28424, 
20.276552, 20.275796, 20.266398, 20.258519, 20.251874, 20.241429, 
20.228231, 20.216457, 20.204968, 20.193763, 20.18094, 20.184923, 
20.182923, 20.183772, 20.186809, 20.198582, 20.209307, 20.209965, 
20.198458, 20.186199, 20.173564, 20.166254, 20.15885), order = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L), hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0.1", "1.1", "2.1", "3.1", "4.1", "5.1", 
"5.2", "6.1", "7.1", "8.1", "9.1", "10.1", "11.1", "12.1", "13.1", 
"14.1", "15.1", "16.1", "17.1", "18.1", "19.1", "20.1", "21.1", 
"22.1", "23.1", "24.1", "25.1", "26.1", "27.1", "28.1", "29.1", 
"30.1", "31.1", "32.1", "33.1", "34.1", "35.1", "36.1", "37.1", 
"38.1", "39.1", "40.1", "41.1", "42.1", "43.1", "44.1", "45.1", 
"46.1", "47.1", "48.1", "49.1", "50.1", "51.1", "52.1", "53.1", 
"54.1", "55.1", "56.1", "57.1", "58.1", "59.1", "60.1", "61.1", 
"62.1", "63.1", "64.1", "65.1", "66.1", "67.1", "68.1", "69.1", 
"70.1", "71.1", "71.2", "72.1", "73.1", "74.1", "75.1", "76.1", 
"77.1", "78.1", "79.1", "80.1", "81.1", "82.1", "83.1", "84.1", 
"85.1", "86.1", "87.1", "87.2", "88.1", "88.2", "89.1", "90.1", 
"91.1", "92.1", "93.1", "94.1", "95.1", "96.1", "97.1", "98.1", 
"99.1", "100.1", "101.1", "102.1", "103.1", "104.1", "105.1", 
"106.1", "107.1", "108.1", "109.1", "110.1", "111.1", "112.1", 
"113.1", "114.1", "115.1", "116.1", "117.1", "118.1", "119.1", 
"120.1", "121.1", "122.1", "123.1", "124.1", "125.1", "126.1", 
"127.1", "128.1", "129.1", "130.1", "131.1", "132.1", "133.1", 
"134.1", "135.1", "136.1", "137.1", "138.1", "139.1", "140.1", 
"141.1", "142.1", "143.1", "144.1", "145.1", "146.1", "147.1", 
"148.1", "149.1", "150.1", "151.1", "152.1", "153.1", "154.1", 
"155.1", "156.1", "157.1", "158.1", "159.1", "160.1", "161.1", 
"162.1", "163.1", "164.1", "165.1", "166.1", "167.1", "168.1"
), class = "factor"), id = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1")), .Names = c("long", "lat", "order", "hole", "piece", 
"group", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(simdat, 100))
structure(list(state = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("", "Andhra Pradesh", "ASSAM", 
"Bihar", "Chandigarh", "CHHATTISGARH", "DADRA & NAGAR HAVELI", 
"DAMAN & DIU", "Delhi", "GOA", "GUJARAT", "Haryana", "Himachal", 
"Jharkhand", "KARNATAKA", "KERALA", "MAHARASHTRA", "MANIPUR", 
"MEGHALAYA", "MP", "Odissa", "PONDICHERRY", "Punjab", "Rajasthan", 
"TAMIL NADU", "TRIPURA", "UP", "Uttrakhand", "WEST BENGAL"), class = "factor"), 
    long = c(78.30000305, 78.30000305, 78.30000305, 78.30000305, 
    78.30000305, 78.30000305, 78.30000305, 78.30000305, 91.5, 
    91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 85.12999725, 85.12999725, 
    85.12999725, 85.12999725, 85.12999725, 85.12999725, 85.12999725, 
    85.12999725, 76.798553, 76.798553, 76.798553, 76.798553, 
    76.798553, 76.798553, 76.798553, 76.798553, 81.62999725, 
    81.62999725, 81.62999725, 81.62999725, 81.62999725, 81.62999725, 
    81.62999725, 81.62999725, 72.96666718, 72.96666718, 72.96666718, 
    72.96666718, 72.96666718, 72.96666718, 72.96666718, 72.96666718, 
    72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 
    72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 
    72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 72.806396, 73.96992109, 
    73.96992109, 73.96992109, 73.96992109, 73.96992109, 73.96992109, 
    73.96992109, 73.96992109, 72.40000153, 72.40000153, 72.40000153, 
    72.40000153, 72.40000153, 72.40000153, 72.40000153, 72.40000153, 
    75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 
    75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 
    75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 75.959473, 85.33000183, 
    85.33000183, 85.33000183, 85.33000183), lat = c(17.20000076, 
    17.20000076, 17.20000076, 17.20000076, 17.20000076, 17.20000076, 
    17.20000076, 17.20000076, 26.09000015, 26.09000015, 26.09000015, 
    26.09000015, 26.09000015, 26.09000015, 26.09000015, 26.09000015, 
    25.37000084, 25.37000084, 25.37000084, 25.37000084, 25.37000084, 
    25.37000084, 25.37000084, 25.37000084, 30.744196, 30.744196, 
    30.744196, 30.744196, 30.744196, 30.744196, 30.744196, 30.744196, 
    21.22999954, 21.22999954, 21.22999954, 21.22999954, 21.22999954, 
    21.22999954, 21.22999954, 21.22999954, 20.26666641, 20.26666641, 
    20.26666641, 20.26666641, 20.26666641, 20.26666641, 20.26666641, 
    20.26666641, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 
    20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 
    20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 20.25189, 15.38429276, 
    15.38429276, 15.38429276, 15.38429276, 15.38429276, 15.38429276, 
    15.38429276, 15.38429276, 23.03000069, 23.03000069, 23.03000069, 
    23.03000069, 23.03000069, 23.03000069, 23.03000069, 23.03000069, 
    29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 
    29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 
    29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 29.017748, 23.35000038, 
    23.35000038, 23.35000038, 23.35000038), value = c(134L, 3L, 
    1098L, 16645L, 123L, 2070L, 37L, 66L, 2L, 4131L, 1L, 21L, 
    0L, 127L, 5L, 651L, 220L, 260L, 1827L, 17596L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 
    22L, 16L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 18L, 450L, 0L, 22L, 30L, 41L, 56L, 
    3L, 53L, 66L, 11L, 4674L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 1L, 328L, 3L, 0L, 
    33L, 0L, 34L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 440L, 0L, 0L, 318L, 16L, 122L, 
    2990L, 35L, 0L, 44L, 1L, 671L, 0L, 43L, 0L, 302L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 40L, 10054L, 379L, 1492L, 160L, 77L, 385L, 4348L, 0L, 
    157L, 59L, 0L, 12L, 334L, 159L, 2013L, 12L, 0L, 3L, 29L, 
    0L, 15L, 16L, 0L, 49L, 10L, 329L), variable = structure(list(
        fact = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
        4L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 
        5L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
        6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 
        1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
        4L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 
        1L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 
        2L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("Buddhist", "Budhist", 
        "Christian", "Hindu", "Jain", "Muslim", "Others", "Sikh"
        ), class = "factor")), .Names = "fact", row.names = c(1L, 
    29L, 57L, 85L, 113L, 141L, 169L, 197L, 2L, 86L, 170L, 198L, 
    30L, 58L, 114L, 142L, 59L, 3L, 143L, 87L, 199L, 31L, 171L, 
    115L, 200L, 172L, 4L, 32L, 60L, 88L, 116L, 144L, 201L, 173L, 
    33L, 61L, 5L, 145L, 117L, 89L, 118L, 6L, 174L, 202L, 90L, 
    146L, 34L, 62L, 175L, 147L, 203L, 7L, 119L, 63L, 91L, 35L, 
    176L, 148L, 120L, 204L, 92L, 8L, 36L, 64L, 121L, 93L, 205L, 
    149L, 177L, 65L, 37L, 9L, 38L, 178L, 94L, 122L, 150L, 66L, 
    206L, 10L, 95L, 179L, 151L, 67L, 39L, 123L, 11L, 207L, 96L, 
    68L, 180L, 124L, 152L, 40L, 208L, 12L, 41L, 13L, 125L, 69L
    ), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("state", "long", "lat", 
"value", "variable"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. If you want help, show us `dput(mapindia)` and `dput(simdat)`

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16054062/640783)? Seems you miss the stats function of your subplot. Try `geom_bar(aes(value, ..count.., fill=fact))`.

Comment: @PauloCardoso..nah,nt working..i had seen that post earlier..but it works with only factors. Here I have factors and their corresponding counts

Comment: @DavidArenburg its a huge database ,but the variables are same as the ones I have given.

Comment: so provide something like `dput(head(mapindia))` etc

Comment: Sorry, True, you are mapping your value column. `stat="identity" ` instead??

Comment: @PauloCardoso-had tried that too.No luck!

Comment: @DavidArenburgdput(head(map))-structure(c("function (database = \"world\", regions = \".\", exact = FALSE, boundary = TRUE, ", 
"    interior = TRUE, projection = \"\", parameters = NULL, orientation = NULL, ", 
"    fill = FALSE, col = 1, plot = TRUE, add = FALSE, namesonly = FALSE, ", 
"    xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, wrap = FALSE, resolution = if (plot) 1 else 0, ", 
"    type = \"l\", bg = par(\"bg\"), mar = c(4.1, 4.1, par(\"mar\")[3], ", 
"        0.1), myborder = 0.01, ...) "), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Comment: dput(head(simdat)) is exceeding the number of characters

Comment: do `dput(head(mapindia, 100))` and `dput(head(simdat, 100))` and insert the results into your **question**, not into the comments

Comment: `religion` also needs a `dput`

Answer (score 1):

There is an [known issue](https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10) with ggsubplot and R3.1.0. See more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23480711/640783) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23636179/640783).

I can plot your data with ggplot but not with ggsubplot

```
library(ggplot2)
df$fact <- df$variable$fact
df$state <- as.character(df$state)
df <- df[ ,-5]
ggplot(df, aes(x = fact, y = value, fill = fact)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  facet_wrap(~state) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()
        ,axis.title.x = element_blank()
        ,axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
        ,strip.text = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image]

If you want to represent your data with pies, you could try something like

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(tsum = sum(value),
         prop = value/tsum)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(1), y=prop, fill = fact1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  facet_wrap(~ state, ncol = 4)  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()
        ,axis.title.x = element_blank()
        ,axis.text.y = element_blank()
        ,axis.title.y = element_blank()
        ,axis.ticks = element_blank()
        ,strip.text = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image]

For subplot, something like this should work:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
india <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'India', ]
dfindia <- fortify(india)
p <- ggplot() +
       geom_polygon(data=dfindia, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) +
       geom_coord()
p + geom_subplot(data=simdat,
             aes(long, lat, group=state,
                 subplot = geom_bar(aes(x=fact, y=value, fill = state),
                                    stat="identity")), width = 10, height=10)
```

Comment: by running your code, it shows : Error: object 'wrld_simpl' not found

Comment: and if i run my code,replacing the last line, again error shows: 'group' not found

Comment: @user2458552 Forgot to load wrld_simpl data. I'm able to create the boxplot with your data, changing the simdat columns to the appropriate format but not the subplot version (in my system).

Comment: can u give the boxplot version?

Comment: @user2458552 I meant `barplot`.

Comment: `p<-ggplot(simdat, aes(state,y=value, fill=factor(variable)))+geom_bar(stat="identity") 
p<-p+facet_grid(facets=. ~ state)
p+coord_polar(theta="y") `

Comment: the above code..should give me a pie diagram for all states..instead it is givin some weird graph..any idea why?@paulo

Comment: @user2458552 Not sure what code you are mentioning. Pie diagram? Without access to the exact code you are using I'll hardly know how to help. Sorry.

Comment: The 4th last comment mentions the code..thats the exact code

Comment: @user2458552 you may want proportions for the pie chart and not the values?

Comment: yes the values has been converted to proportions..yet the pie charts show individual rings for each of the variables.

Comment: ..the original question I asked has already been dwelt with it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465070/barplots-on-a-map/24015776#24015776  but that is also giving an Error.

Comment: sorry, but this may be elementary..but could you tell the diff between fact1 and factor(1)?

Comment: fact1 is a new variable with the proportions for each state. factor(1) is just a way to map each state pie to the total proportion (=1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54995/discussion-between-user2458552-and-paulo-cardoso).